# Converting C# project to SDK style results in "Platform 'x64' is used in project file but not mentioned in $(Platforms)."

Tags: visual-studio, migration, project

I try to convert "old school" csproj files in latest VS 2019 to SDK style projects using

```
dotnet-migrate-2019.exe wizard myapplication.csproj
```

I get the following warnings:

```
Platform 'x64' is used in project file but not mentioned in $(Platforms).
```

These are INFO level messages but when conversion finishes, project files have all pre- and post-build events gone.
What do these platform messages mean and how do I get rid of them in hope that my pre- and post-build events will remain intact?

Comment: Can you share your project file? Ideally both before and after the conversion.

Comment: Also, perhaps try this tool instead: https://github.com/dotnet/try-convert

Answer (score 0):

The following fixed the platform-related error messages in my project. However I had no pre-/post build events.

1. Add the Platforms tag to the 'main' property group:

```
   <PropertyGroup>
    <Platforms>AnyCPU;x86;x64</Platforms>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net48</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

2. Add the PlatformTarget tags into all the platforms mentioned in the above added Platforms (the way it was in the old csproj format), for examle:

```
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <PlatformTarget>x86</PlatformTarget>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <PlatformTarget>x86</PlatformTarget>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|x64'">
    <PlatformTarget>x64</PlatformTarget>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|x64'">
    <PlatformTarget>x64</PlatformTarget>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|x86'">
    <PlatformTarget>x86</PlatformTarget>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|x86'">
    <PlatformTarget>x86</PlatformTarget>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Now you might get the following error when changing the build Platform in VS: "Current solution contains incorrect configuration mappings. It may cause projects to not work correctly. Open the Configuration Manager to fix them."

The solution to this one is: Close the solution, delete the .vs Folder next to the solution and re-open the solution.